# Reduce EBS volume

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I know about increasing, but is there a way reduce the size of an EBS volume? Like I've put effort into my AMI but soon realized it's way to big for my needs. It's a windows 2008 instance.

Comment: Hi Martin, I've just tried with a 2003R2 datacenter instance and managed to shrink this from 35GB to 12GB. That was done by cloning the entire EBS volume in windows and then restarting with the smaller cloned EBS image. So there might be a chance you can do the same with Windows 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No answer. It seems like you can't do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a snapshot of the volume and then create an ebs volume from the snapshot which is smaller.  The snapshot will have a 'volume size' to give you an idea of how small you can go as I understand it.

I guess if the snapshot route doesn't work, you can just create the smaller volume, copy the larger to the smaller and then get rid of the larger.

Comment: No I can't, I can make it larger but not smaller than the "capacity", at least not in anyway I can see at first glance. If I try it'll say "Volume size 1GiB must be at least snapshot size 30GiB."

Comment: Interesting.  My 30gb volume results in a 1gb snapshot, and I can then create a 3gb volume from the snapshot.  But I'm working with linux, perhaps the windows volumes work differently.